# AWK print line from File A if string in 2 columns are both present in File B

Tags: awk

I am trying to pull out lines where Col1 and Col2 from FileA are present in FileB.

For example,

FileA:

```
1000963 4852419 0.051 0.0103 0.1126
1001037 1957033 0.044 0.0154 0.0473
1001107 1690854 0.045 0.0145 0.0612
1001176 1996721 0.067 0 0.2494
```

FileB:

```
1281525
1000963
1690854
1001176
1001037
1957033
1996721
5784681
```

In the example above, I would expect the output to be:

```
1001037 1957033 0.044 0.0154 0.0473
1001176 1996721 0.067 0 0.2494
```

Note that the other two lines were not pulled out because only a string in one column (not both columns) was present in FileB.

Is there a way of doing this in awk? My attempts have not worked so far.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}  (($1 in a) && ($2 in a))' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                       ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file2 is being read.
  a[$0]                        ##Creating array a with index $0 here.
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(($1 in a) && ($2 in a))       ##Checking if current line 1st and 2nd  field both are present in array then print current line.
' Input_file2  Input_file1     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Will add explanation shorty to answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you - this is much simpler than the way I was trying to do it! Thanks - it works :)

Comment: @LauraC, Glad that it helped you, deleting question I leave up to you,cheers and keep learning and sharing on this great site SO cheers buddy :)

Comment: @LauraC: There is no need to delete your question and it is not fair also after someone has invested time & efforts and posted an answer.

Comment: @anubhava I decided not to delete it in the end as the comments from another user have been deleted. If you had seen the multiple comments you would have understood why I was considering deleting. I am going to leave it up because I am grateful for the answer and hopefully it will help others searching for similar answers :)

Comment: @LauraC Thanks for your comment and I believe you have taken right stand.